# getting more info on "permission denied"

Tags: bash, permissions

I am getting a 'permission denied' error on a script. I already checked all the usual suspects:

- I own the file and folder
- Both have the `x` permission
- In fact both are `rwx` to the owner, which is the user I'm using.

The script shebang line is `#!/bin/sh` which I can execute fine. But that is irrelevant as it is never even parsed. Setting `-x` on my current bash session will not show anything else happening other than trying to execute the script.

The error I get is:

```
$ path/script
bash: path/script: Permission denied
$ _
```

edit: if i pass the script as an argument, it works fine

```
$ /bin/sh -x path/script
...script executes...
```

Comment: ok, it was a silly cause. the mount flag had `noexec`. but i would still like the answer to the questions "getting more info on “permission denied”"

Comment: Is the `path/script` on a mounted file system with `noexec` set on the mount?  …I hit return and see that the answer is "yes"…  There isn't a way to get more information; that's all the information the shell has, because that's all the information the kernel tells the shell.  You have to debug it by checking the access permissions.  You were following most of the right steps.  What you omitted to tell us was the actual path, and that it was on a file system mounted with `noexec`.  There's no way for anyone not on the machine to know that — it is found out by a process of elimination.

Comment: yeah. that was the ultimate cause, as i said above, of the permission denied. but i'd like to know how to actually get more information instead of checking a dozen things everytime...

Comment: Note that in general, things like ACLs can really confuse the issue.

Comment: POSIX isn't designed to give you more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get more information by diving into the kernel calls.  It helps if you have a knowledge of C, and the kernel APIs.  `man` pages are your friends.

See if you have a program called `strace` try `which strace`.  There are similar programs on various UNIXs (like `truss` on some Suns, `dtruss` on OS X) but `strace` is the most common.  If you can't find one, Google something like "strace  for ....", whatever UNIX you are using.

```
strace -o strace.out -f /bin/sh path/script
```

`-o strace.out`  means trace to the file `strace.out` - look at it using an editor

`-f` means follow child processes.

`/bin/sh path/script` is the program you are tracing.

You will get a lot of output, sometimes it is worth going to the end and working backwards.

On Linux there is also `ltrace` which can trace library calls as well.

If the program you wish to trace is already running, then the `-p` option, followed by the `pid` of the process, can be very handy.

Of course, having said all that it is quite possible in this case that the shell was reporting all that the kernel was telling it.  It might be that there was no further information to give.

Comment: Joanthan was right. the kernel says nothing about the cause. i got: `execve("path/script", ["path/script"...], [/* 36 vars */]) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied) \n write(2, "strace: exec: Permission denied\n", 32) = 32 \n exit_group(1)                           = ? \n +++ exited with 1 +++
`

Comment: `ltrace` complains it is not a binary elf. i'm not familiar with ltrace yet.

Comment: Jonathan is usually (maybe always?) right.  Anyway, now you know how to get the real story.  Application programs often do not report the full story, `strace` is a good tool to know.

Comment: With `ltrace`, make sure you specify the executable, not just the script name (I made a mistake on my first version of the post by omitting /bin/sh).

Comment: Definitely not 'always right', though I try to make it better than just 'more often than not'.